# How do i configure my content to show full posts?

Tags: content, excerpt

So my blog is currently http://www.joegilbertphotography.co.uk/blog/ using the “delight” theme. Can anybody tell me how on earth I change it so instead of showing excerpts of posts, it just shows the entire post, one after the other, for about five posts or so, on the main landing page?

I've tried changing the_excerpt to the_content, which just makes the whole lot disappear. I've also tried asking the creator of the template with no joy.

Please help this is driving me nuts!  Many thanks

---

Thanks Sagive,

I've tried changing every entry of excerpt to content, all successfully other than one line which makes everything vanish when I amend it in any way. You can (hopefully) see my code at:

http://pastebin.com/Fkr3eTrW

thanks very much!

---

any ideas anyone? Really stuck on this! Thanks

Comment: Please don't create answers for discussion. Edit your question or use comments. You might need to properly register on site for that to work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You Should go into index.php and

**change:**

```
the_excerpt(); //or similer
```

**to:**

```
the content();
```

If your code looks different paste it in pastebin and share a link.

Best of luck, Sagive.